# How to disable ios UIAlertView from appearing while playing dailymotion video through ios sdk in my app

Tags: ios, uialertview, dailymotion-api

I am developing my app which plays dailymotion videos using the dailymotion's iOS SDK. While playing a video an alertview appears with a message that reads **"You are about to leave App Name, if user wants to open the dailymotion in the safari browser"** with open and close button.

My question is that how can I prevent this alertview from appearing in the application.

Comment: Blame the Dailymotion's SDK. UIAlertView are System and it's not really possible to stop them (Apple wouldn't want you to do it).

Comment: Hi @youshea. Can you post here the URL it then opens in Safari? This alert is supposed to redirect you to Safari when trying to load a non-Dailymotion Video URL via the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to diable the UIAlertView by commenting out the code in the dailymotion sdk that would enable the alertview.